# Where did the Firefox canvas debugger go?

Tags: firefox, debug

I recently run into a nasty bug in my canvas drawing code. Since I use Firefox, I naturally reached for the [Canvas Debugger](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/03/introducing-the-canvas-debugger-in-firefox-developer-tools/). To my surprise, I found that it wasn't there any more. Does anyone know what's happened to it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was removed as of [Firefox 67](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Deprecated_tools#Canvas_debugger) due to lack of maintenance.

Comment: Ah, right. Thanks for the information! It's a real shame, because I found it rather useful actually.